# How many Cauchy epsilons are there for a given series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

The Cauchy Criterion for convergence states that if a series converges, it is both necessary and sufficient that

$$\forall \varepsilon \exists N:\forall n,m > N, \sum_{n}^{m}a_n < \varepsilon.$$

The contrapositive of this is:

$$\exists\varepsilon :\forall N, \exists n,m > N : \sum_{n}^{m}a_n \geq \varepsilon.$$

In the convergent case, its obvious that all $\varepsilon$ work. In the divergent case, is it reasonable to assume there could be multiple $\varepsilon$'s that work? A sketch of an idea would be that we can vary our interval [n,m] with $\varepsilon$ to find a suitable value for any $\varepsilon$, but this seems naive to me. Can anyone answer definitively or supply a better proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum_n^m a_n \geq \varepsilon > 0$, then $\sum_n^m a_n \geq \varepsilon'$ for all $\varepsilon' \in (0, \varepsilon)$. So all the $\varepsilon' \in (0, \varepsilon)$ work.

Comment: This is great, thank you. If I'm reading this right there are a countably infinite number of usable values. Follow up question: can we assume some $\varepsilon$'s outside of that given interval will also work?

Comment: Countably, and even uncountably ! For your second question, the answer is no in general. For example, with $a_n = (-1)^n$ the value $\varepsilon = 1$ works, but it is the maximal value that works.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Thinking a bit more about this -- in general there will be a maximum value. I suppose this isn't always the case, and some (possibly pathological objects) will have many such values and hence no maximum $\varepsilon$ at all. For a series with an infinite limit at infinity, for example, we will always be able to find an $\varepsilon$ it is greater than. Is there a known set of qualities that guarantee a maximum satisfactory value exists? Is it true for the majority (in the Erdos sense?) of series that diverge?

Comment: Well, examples with no maximum value of $\varepsilon$ are not always pathological. For example, with $a_n = 1$, all the $\varepsilon > 0$ work. More generally, you can easily see that if $a_n \geq 0$ and the series $\sum a_n$ diverges, then all the $\varepsilon$ work !

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your notation in the last sentence -- any $a_n$ where the terms are non - negative will have multiple satisfactory $\varepsilon$? Or do you mean if the series is nondecreasing?

Comment: If $a_n \geq 0$, then the series (ie the sequence of partial sums of $\sum a_n$) is increasing, yes. And because we ask it to diverge, it has to tend to $+\infty$. You can see now why every $\varepsilon$ work.

Comment: Yes, I think this is clear to me now -- divergence implies the sum is always increasing, so we may always find a $\varepsilon$ which the sum is greater than for all n greater than another N? Hope my clumsy attempt to translate the quantifiers here makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it is the idea. Fix any $\varepsilon > 0$, and any $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Because the sum $\sum_{k=N}^n a_k$ tends to $+\infty$ when $n$ tends to $+\infty$, there exists $m$ such that $\sum_{k=N}^m a_k \geq \varepsilon$. Taking $n=N$, and the $m$ you just chose, you have the property.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks again for your help.